# Select active tab in uib-tabset ui-bootstrap angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I'm trying to select active tab with uib-tabset in ui-bootstrap library.
Seems like that setting active="1" or active="0" has no effect on the active tab.
documentation is in here 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Example:

```
<uib-tabset active="1">
    <uib-tab heading="tab1" index="0">
      ........
    </uib-tab>

    <uib-tab heading="tab2" index="1">
      ..........
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of angular-ui-bootstrap? And also which files you have included from library?

Comment: Same example is working for me. https://plnkr.co/edit/02qexEXIaUpDxoar3fux?p=preview

Comment: Same here: https://plnkr.co/edit/vLIcTrdpxMGLIVJz8IaI?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: As I commented, it was a version specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I was able to fix it, I'm using an older version (1.x) so solution is:

```
<uib-tabset >
    <uib-tab heading="tab1" active="true">
      ........
    </uib-tab>

    <uib-tab heading="tab2" >
      ..........
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```